# How to hide the xAxis and yAxis title of Django Chartit chart?

Tags: python, django

I want to hide the x/y axis title in a small chart. I tried removing `xAxis` and `yAxis` fields from `chart_options`, but result is same. Could somebody help?

```
   return Chart(
        datasource=blockpivotdata,
        series_options=[{
            'options': {
                'type': 'line',
                'stacking': False
            },
            'terms': {
                'date': [
                    'num',
                ]
            }
        }],
        chart_options={
            'title': {
                'text': 'Block Count Chart'},
            'xAxis': {
                'title': {
                    'text': 'Date'}},          <<<< this one
            'yAxis': {
                'title': {
                    'text': 'Blocks'}},        <<<< and this one
            'legend': {
                'enabled': False},
            'credits': {
                'enabled': False}},
    )
```

BTW, I'm using `Django version 2.0`, `django-chartit 0.2.9`, and `Python 3.7.0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide it you could do one of following

```
plt.axis('off')
```

or

```
ax1 = plt.axes()
ax1.xaxis.set_label_text('foo')
ax1.xaxis.label.set_visible(False)
```

removing the words inside the `title` while storing them in a variable is also an option

Comment: Tried `plt.axis('off')` but fail with `'Chart' object has no attribute 'axis'`.  And tried `ax1 = plt.axes()`, fail with `'Chart' object has no attribute 'axes'`

Comment: I don't understand, what's the meaning of `the text line in the chart file`?  which file?

Answer (score 0):

Later, I find a solution and just want to paste here in case anyone need it.

```
    chart_options={
        'title': {
            'text': 'Your Title'
        },
        'xAxis': [
            {
                'title': {
                    'text': 'Date',
                    'style': {
                        'display': 'none'
                    }
                },
                'labels': {
                    'enabled': True
                }
            },
            {
                'title': {
                    'text': 'Date',
                    'style': {               <<<< 
                        'display': 'none'    <<<< use this to hide axis title
                    }
                },
                'labels': {
                    'enabled': False
                },
                'lineColor': 'transparent',
                'tickLength': 0,
            }
        ],
        'yAxis': [
            {
                'title': {
                    'text': 'Blocks',
                    'style': {
                        'color': '#70b3ef'
                    }
                },
                'labels': {
                    'enabled': False
                },
            },
            {
                'title': {
                    'text': 'Total Diff'
                },
                'labels': {
                    'enabled': False
                }
            }
        ],
        'legend': {
            'enabled': False
        },
    }
```

And you can see an alive example here: https://grinexplorer.net